# Bulk rename files after sed -i

Tags: bash, sed, awk, find, file-rename

This script correctly finds the files I need and replaces consecutive spaces with a single space:

```
find . -type f -iname *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-* ! -iname *.gz ! -iname *_processed -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i  's/ \+ / /g'
```

What I need now is to append `_parsed` to the end of each file's **filename** so that the files are ignored the next time this script is run.

What is a good way to do this? Note: the files have no extension. The filenames look like this:

```
./1923/338810-99999-1923
./1921/999999-41406-1921
./1953/320590-99999-1953
./1911/241360-99999-1911
./1923/307330-99999-1923
./1983/802220-99999-1983
```

Edit: I am using CentOS 6. Python-based solutions would work as well.

Comment: many seds that accept the `-i` option accept an optional extension, so try | xargs sed -i "_parsed" 's/...//'`. You many need to remove the space separating the `-i` from the extension value. Test it on one file first, right:-? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to combine your current script *with* the ability to append the string, you can put the results of your `find` into a `while` loop and do both at the same time (`while` instead of `for` to support files with spaces, if you ever need this condition - thanks to @TimPote for the tip!):

```
find . -type f -iname *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-* ! -iname *.gz ! -iname *_processed -print | while read file; do \
    sed -i 's/ \+ / /g' "$file"; \
    mv "$file" "${file}_parsed"; \
done
```

An alternative, just to rename, would be to use `find`'s `-exec` option:

```
find . -type f -iname *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-* ! -iname *.gz ! -iname *_processed -exec mv {} "{}_parsed" \;
```

This command will iterate through the same list of files that your original find+replace command finds, but this time will just rename them as you wanted.

Comment: Your first solution will break if the files happen to have spaces anywhere in the path.  I know that he *says* the files look a certain way, but you can't be too certain.  A better way, using the same approach would be `find . [...] | while read file; do [...] done;`  `find` guarantees that each file will be on a new line, and `while read` reads exactly one line at a time into the variable `file`.

Comment: @TimPote I actually didn't even think of that to be honest - thanks for the tip; I've updated my answer to use `while` instead of `for`!

Comment: @Tim Pote Why worry about spaces in filenames if you're not going to worry about newlines in filenames?